# How to use a counter to set section or chapter or subsection based on counter value?

Tags: sectioning, counters

Suppose I have my own counter as in

```
\newcounter{x}
\setcounter{x}{0}
```

and now I want to start a new "section" based on the value of `x`. For example, if `x==-1` I want  `\part`, and if `x==0` then it will be `\chapter` and if `x==1` it will be `\section` and so on.

I do not want to write each time something like this (do not even know it is valid syntax)

```
   \ifnum \value{x} \eq  -1
         \part             
   \else
        \ifnum \value{x} \eq 0
           \chapter
        ...
        \fi
  \fi
  ...
```

I'd like to just write

```
  \makeSectionTypeBasedOnThisValue{x}{title of the section of chapter is here}
```

and this command will map to the correct command based on the value of `x`.  I will make sure `x` is always between -1 and 5 since these are the valid values. I am using book style.

I have a reason to want to do it this way. (briefly, I am building my large tree of latex documents, combining them to one document, and I want to be able to build it starting from any level going down. Hence depending on where in the tree I start the build, section numbering will be different. One time the same level can be a `\section` while some other time that level can become a `\subsection`. So I do not want to hardcode the `\section` or `\chapter` commands in Latex files, but I want these to depend on the level the file is in the tree. The counter will represent the level in the tree I am starting the build from)

Is there is an easy way to do this? I am a newbie in Latex.

Comment: Did you try something like `\def\Sect#1#2{\ifcase#1\or \part\or\chapter\or\…\fi\relax #2}`? If you want to start counter from -1, you'll need to increment in before `\ifcase` or do other check.

Comment: @Eddy_Em, no I have not. This is advanced for me. As I said I am newbie in Latex programming. Will try it now and see. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\ifcase`, you can selectively step through possible numeric values:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcounter{myseccntr}
\newcommand{\makeSectionTypeBasedOnThisValue}[1]{%
  \setcounter{myseccntr}{\numexpr#1+1}%
  \ifcase\value{myseccntr}% -1
    \expandafter\part
  \or % 0
    \expandafter\chapter
  \or % 1
    \expandafter\section
  \or % 2
    \expandafter\subsection
  \or % 3
    \expandafter\subsubsection
  \or % 4
    \expandafter\paragraph
  \or % 5
    \expandafter\subparagraph
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\makeSectionTypeBasedOnThisValue{-1}{Part}
\makeSectionTypeBasedOnThisValue{0}{Chapter}
\makeSectionTypeBasedOnThisValue{1}{Section}
\makeSectionTypeBasedOnThisValue{2}{Subsection}
\makeSectionTypeBasedOnThisValue{1}{Section}
\makeSectionTypeBasedOnThisValue{-1}{Part}
\makeSectionTypeBasedOnThisValue{0}{Chapter}
\makeSectionTypeBasedOnThisValue{1}{Section}
\end{document}
```